# Unclear about fluctuating frequency when using NPN transistor

Tags: transistors, npn

I am trying to build a more complex circuit but am having trouble starting off. I am using tone() to generate a frequency on my 5V Arduino Nano on D3. If I measure the frequency directly at D3 to GND, I measure a consistent 123.15hz which is what I'm looking for. Now, If I use an NPN transistor(I have tried a S8050 and BC337) the frequency jumps between 107hz and 123hz when I measure at the emitter. I am using a 1k ohm resistor in between D3 and the base of the NPN.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

[image: ?Basic NPN Diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1st، as others have pointed out this problem, you have to change your wiring, connect the +5v wire to the collector (left side pin of the transistor in the schematic) & connect GND wire to the emitter (right side pin of the transistor)
- 2nd, in this schematic, you are measuring the current of transistor's output, not it's voltage. Remove the measuring instrument, replace it by a resistor as your load, then connect the measuring instrument to the load resistor in parallel (connect measuring instrument to both pins of the load resistor).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand I had the emitter and collector backwards. I have made the changes you suggested. I see the flaw in my drawing and testing method. I now have a steady frequency.

Comment: Best of luck user3255843

Answer (score 3):

Your transistor seems to be connected backwards.
What is that thing connected between the emitter and 5V, is that your measuring instrument? There needs to be a load between transistor and the power supply poles.
Your set up just seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your NPN is reversed. The right way is collector on positive side and emitter negative. You also missed the loading resistor - usually its connected in collector side.

Answer (score 3):

This was the correct way to wire and check the frequency.

[image: Working Version]

Comment: I want an LCD with that font.